# ¿Como hacer responsivo un elemento agregado manualmente al diseño predeterminado de una plantilla?

Tags: html, css, wordpress-theme

Tengo una plantilla wordpress la cuál tiene diseño responsivo pero agregue algunos elementos html y css, y estos que fuerón agregados no se adaptan al diseño responsivo del  diseño,  cuando hago el navegador mas chico, no se adapta el div agregado a diseño responsive.
 ¿que tengo que agregar para que se adapten también?
Estos son lo que agregue en pagina html y archivo css.

```html
<div class="caja" style="text-align: center;">Patrocinador</div>
```

```css
.caja {

font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 30px;
font-weight: 400;

color: #ffffff;

background: #000000;

overflow: hidden;
padding: 20px;
text-align: center;
margin: auto;

height: 25px;
width: 1130px;



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al estar trabajando con tu caja en medidas `PX`, siempre va coger *1130px* como ancho fijo de pantalla, con lo cual no se hace responsivo.

Una solución podría ser: cambiando `width: 1130px;` a `max-width: 1130px;` y añadimos un `width:100%;`

Con esto estamos diciendo que el *ancho* de nuestra caja va ser el *100%* de pantalla, pero su máximo permitida es *1130 pixeles*, con lo cual en pantallas con un ancho superior solo va rellenar 1130px de pantalla.

```css
   

.caja {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #000000;
  overflow: hidden;   
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  /* Reglas responsivo */
  width:100%;
  max-width: 1130px;      
}

/* Modificamos algunos valores en pantallas con 500px de ancho o inferior si uno lo desea */
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .caja {    
    font-size: 20px;    
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="caja">Patrocinador</div>
```

En pantallas por ejemplo *HD* o superiores a *1130px*, te va rellenar solamente *1130px*, ya que con el `max-width` estamos declarando su maximo permitido en *px*. Si la pantalla es inferior a *1130px* si te va rellenar el *100%* como se puede observar en el ejemplo cuando se ejecuta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solución para que la caja rellene el total de pantalla:

```css
  

.caja {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #000000;
  overflow: hidden;   
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  /* Reglas responsivo */
  width:100%;
  /* Solución */
  max-width: 100%;      
}

/* Modificamos algunos valores en pantallas con 500px de ancho o inferior si uno lo desea */
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .caja {    
    font-size: 20px;        
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="caja">Patrocinador</div>
```

Ejemplo Pantalla *HD*:

Al trabajar con *%* si que se se hace responsivo a cualquier resolución de pantalla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: de acuerdo, gracias, disculpe y ¿para que el elemento div en tamaño normal abarque todo el ancho de la pantalla, que no deje margenes a los lados?

Comment: @ArmandoArellano en pantalla normal para que tome el ancho total de pantalla, podrías añadir un `@media screen and (max-width:medida deseado)` y modificas tu `.caja` a `max-width:100%;`, ahora si siempre deseas que tome el ancho total de pantalla y responsivo, simplemente modificas `max-width` a `100%`. ¡Un saludo!

Comment: busco que abarque el ancho total, ¿podrías agregarlo a la respuesta, por favor?

Comment: @ArmandoArellano te e modificado mi respuesta, te he añadido otro ejemplo con lo cual *.caja* se adapta de manera responsivo al ancho total de cualquier pantalla.

Comment: mucchas gracias, saludos